# Enabling ACL for Open Source Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

We have an open source confluent schema registry setup running and have been able to manage schemas with it. We want to restrict access by using ACLs. Is this available to do with open source version?

I checked the following places:

1. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/confluent-security-plugins/schema-registry/authorization/sracl_authorizer.html
2. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/confluent-security-plugins/schema-registry/authorization/index.html#example-acl-setups
3. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/confluent-security-plugins/schema-registry/introduction.html#confluentsecurityplugins-schema-registry-security-plugin
   According to this, I didn't find anything helpful.

I want to try adding ACLs to the `_schemas` topic directly. Will this help in managing access to schemas themselves?

Comment: You can add HTTP Basic Auth to the Registry REST API. Topic ACLS are for the Registry server itself to prevent direct access to the topic for Kafka clients, not external HTTP clients

Comment: He asked about authorization(acls) not authentication, any update on this please ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to try adding ACLs to the _schemas topic directly. Will this help in managing access to schemas themselves?

Answer is - no, it will not help. Schema Registry uses it is own account to connect to `_schemas` topic. And it's need `all` right. When you connect to Schema Registry it will connect you and add to you rights throw it is own rights(all). So you need to add confluent plugin to add some ACL rights, elswhere you will have `all` rights